# PySpark - How to filter a consecutive chunk of rows out of a dataframe based on two values in a column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've one dataframe and I want to create another dataframe based on some column values using `pyspark`.
For example : below is my main dataframe -

```
Part1   Part2   Part3   Part4
aaa      up      24     k-123
bbb     down     45     i-98
ccc     down     54     k-89
fff     int      23     l-34
xyz      up      22     o-89
www      up      89     u-56
```

Now, I want to create another dataframe which will search for 1st occurrence of 'down' and will go till 1st occurrence of 'up'. So, the expected dataframe would be :

```
   Part1    Part2   Part3   Part4
    bbb     down     45     i-98
    ccc     down     54     k-89
    fff     int      23     l-34
    xyz      up      22     o-89
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Creating the `DataFrame`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col, lit
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('aaa','up',24,'k-123'),('bbb','down',45,'i-98'),('ccc','down',54,'k-89'),
     ('fff','int', 23,'l-34'),('xyz','up',22,'o-89'),('www','up',89,'u-56')], 
    schema = ['Part1','Part2','Part3','Part4']
)
df.show()
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|Part1|Part2|Part3|Part4|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  aaa|   up|   24|k-123|
|  bbb| down|   45| i-98|
|  ccc| down|   54| k-89|
|  fff|  int|   23| l-34|
|  xyz|   up|   22| o-89|
|  www|   up|   89| u-56|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

**Step 2:** First we need to find the first occurrence of `down` and delete all the rows above it. To do so we create a column `cumulative`, with value 1 if `Part2` == `down` and 0 otherwise and finally taking a cumulative sum of this column.

```
df = df.withColumn('Dummy',lit('dummy'))
df = df.withColumn('cumulative',when(col('Part2')=='down',1).otherwise(0))
df = df.selectExpr(
    'Part1','Part2','Part3','Part4','Dummy',
    'sum(cumulative) over (order by row_number() over (order by Dummy)) as cumulative'
 )
df.show()
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+
|Part1|Part2|Part3|Part4|Dummy|cumulative|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+
|  aaa|   up|   24|k-123|dummy|         0|
|  bbb| down|   45| i-98|dummy|         1|
|  ccc| down|   54| k-89|dummy|         2|
|  fff|  int|   23| l-34|dummy|         2|
|  xyz|   up|   22| o-89|dummy|         2|
|  www|   up|   89| u-56|dummy|         2|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+
```

Now, remove all rows where cumulative sum is 0. This will remove all rows till `down` appears for the first time.

```
df = df.where(col('cumulative')>=1)
```

**Step 3:** Do the same as in Step 2 above, except that do it for `up` and remove all rows where value in column `cumulative` is less than or equal to 1. This way we will remove all rows below the first occurrence of `up`.

```
df = df.withColumn('cumulative',when(col('Part2')=='up',1).otherwise(0))
df = df.selectExpr(
    'Part1','Part2','Part3','Part4','Dummy',
    'sum(cumulative) over (order by row_number() over (order by Dummy)) as cumulative'
 )
df = df.where(col('cumulative')<=1).drop('Dummy','cumulative')
df.show()
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|Part1|Part2|Part3|Part4|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  bbb| down|   45| i-98|
|  ccc| down|   54| k-89|
|  fff|  int|   23| l-34|
|  xyz|   up|   22| o-89|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```